# Proving a matrix is positive definite using Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If you have a Hermitian matrix $C$ that you can rewrite using Cholesky decomposition, how can you use this to show that $C$ is also positive definite?
$C$ is positive definite if $x^\top C x > 0$ and $x$ is a vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition):

> If A can be written as LL* for some invertible L, lower triangular or
>   otherwise, then A is Hermitian and positive definite.

$A=LL^*\implies x^*Ax=(L^*x)^*(L^*x)\ge 0$

Since $L$ is invertible, $L^*x\ne 0$ unless $x=0$, so $x^*Ax>0\ \forall\ x\ne 0$

Comment: I know that's what wikipedia says, but how do you prove that to be the case?

Comment: @user1855952: Sounds good now?

Comment: I see. I'm just a little bit confused over one step where you do x*Ax = (L*x)*(L*x). So x*Ax = x*(LL*)x which you could split up as (x*L)*(L*x) but that's different from what you have.

Answer (score 3):

If $C = LL^{\ast}$ with $L$ lower triangular, then
$$ \langle Cx, x \rangle = \langle LL^{\ast} x, x \rangle = \langle L^{\ast} x, L^{\ast} x \rangle \geq 0$$
Thus $C$ is positive semi-definite. Note that, as stated, you cannot show that $C$ is positive definite unless you also know that $L$ is invertible.

Comment: How do you go from <LL*x, x> to <L*x, L*x> ? And then I still don't see how that is necessarily >= 0

Comment: The very definition of $A^{\ast}$ is that $\langle Ax, x \rangle = \langle x, A^{\ast} x \rangle$.